# Check box for Column listview Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox

How to create Check box for Column inside Listview. i was able to make checkbox for listview items. but i want to have checkbox for Column itself.like in windows:

[image]

here is code in XAML

```
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Width="400">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Column1 With Checkbox">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Tag="{Binding}" IsThreeState="False" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Column2" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="115" Header="Column3" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Note that this will only make checkboxes for items not Column itself. so how to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the header a custom control by defining it under the `GridViewColumn.Header` property.

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Width="400">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140">
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Checkbox IsChecked="{Binding YourCheckedProperty}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Column1" />
                    </StackPanel>
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Column2" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="115" Header="Column3" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: but how to have them both. i mean the name of column..how to have both GridViewColumn.Header and Header="Column1" ,,, i cant do it. is that separated column?

Comment: See edit... You can put anything under `GridViewColumn.Header`. For your case, you can wrap the `CheckBox` and the `TextBlock` under a `Stackpanel`.

Comment: thank you very much, so `GridViewColumn.Header` changes the header in more detail.